# Doctrine 2: columnDefinition ENUM not working

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I want to use ENUM in my class but TINYINT in my database. I followed this article: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/mysql-enums.html

In my Mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `side` (
  `coated` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 = Uncoated; 1 = Coated',
);
```

In my class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('coated', 'uncoated')")
 */
private $coated = null;
```

Running the values in PHP I get the real value from database:

```
0 or 1
```

I'm wondering if this solution works using Mysql. Hope having a solution, if this won't work the only solution I find is:

```
public function getCoated() {
  if ($this->coated === 0){
    return "uncoated";
  } elseif ($this->coated === 1) {
    return "coated";
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "TINYINT" I suggest to use "BIT" data type, so that database will only allow storing the values as "0" or "1" to be in safe side.

Your existing:

```
CREATE TABLE `side` (
  `coated` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 = Uncoated; 1 = Coated'
);
```

Change it to:

```
CREATE TABLE `side` (
  `coated` BIT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 = Uncoated; 1 = Coated'
);
```

In "TINYINT" it can also accept the values other than 0/1 that might be create a bug in your application if someone updated your table data to like 2,3,4.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this don't work. When printing the values: for 0 it gets nothing, for 1 it gets this character [EDIT: I can't paste the character, but it's similar to an r]